# Unable to use variable variables to execute function in PHP 5.5

Tags: php, php-5.5

My self and another developer have both installed Lamp on two separate systems (Ubuntu & OSX) and for some odd reason the package we develop internally no longer works on PHP 5.5 (5.5.9 in my case)

One area in particular is:

```
if (method_exists($this, 'hook_' . __FUNCTION__)) {
    $this->{'hook_' . __FUNCTION__}();
}
```

The above code results in an error stating that a method named `hook_xxx` doesn't exist, however if we replace the code with:

```
if (method_exists($this, 'hook_' . __FUNCTION__)) {
    call_user_func(array($this, 'hook_' . __FUNCTION__));
}
```

It works perfectly.

To make matters worse, this works on PHP 5.4.33..

I've just spent 2 days fannying around with PHPBrew etc trying to get PHP 5.4.33 installed properly and think the solution is actually trying to find out why it's failing in the first place.

Any idea's?

Thanks

Gavin

---

The error I get is:

```
Call to undefined method LocalController::hook_index()
```

Where I have:

```
<?php

    class Controller
    {
        public function index() {

            echo 'Parent index called';

            if (method_exists($this, 'hook_' . __FUNCTION__)) {
                $this->{'hook_' . __FUNCTION__}();
            }
        }
    }

    class LocalController extends Controller
    {
        public function hook_index() {

            echo 'Child index called';

        }
    }
```

The app it self will load in Controller and then if it exists, it will load in LocalController.

This all works fine on 5.4 or if I change it to use call_user_func, however dies with the above error otherwise.

Comment: What is the exact error that you're getting?

Comment: Works for me, Mac OS X running PHP 5.5.14.

Comment: I suppose that would actually help ;) See above

Comment: It does look as though you are calling the method on `$this` while in the context of `Controller`, while the `hook_index` method is a member of the class `LocalController`, and neither class extends the other.  That said, the method truly does not exist in `(Controller) $this`.  Did I miss something?

Comment: it should work fine, have a look http://3v4l.org/FiEJB#v500. As Michael said, there is no `hook_index` in the `Controller` class, is that normal ? Also, what's the point with `$this->response->setOutput($this->render());` here ? I don't think this is related to your problem so IMHO you could remove it (it'll improve code readability too). Finally, the example with both class looks incomplete: you can't get *this* error out of this code because the code only declare 2 classes and the method `Controller::index` is never called. Can you add the lines which triggers the error ? Thanks :)

Comment: We have a proparitory system which comes as a core package. All of our classes can be overridden by simply extending the original and prefixing the class name with Local. This provides access to the existing methods if required. In addition to this, we also provide hooks (i.e. hook_functionname) which is called after the original, which allows you to interact before the response is sent back.

Comment: Proprietary as in custom C binaries?  Because simply adding `Local` to something does not an extension make, you usually need the `extends` keyword, or, if available, at least a `use` declaration.  If your "system" deviates from this significantly, or implements custom binaries, it is likely that we will not be of much help...

Comment: No no, we're using plain ol' PHP. See my OP which contains an example of Controller and LocalController. In terms of this, LocalController contains `hook_index` and Controller is configured to execute `hook_index` if it exists. If `index` doesn't exist in LocalController, it will call `index` on Controller.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing string concatenation and call in separate steps

```
        $f = 'hook_' . __FUNCTION__;
        print('testing function ' . $f);

        if (method_exists($this, $f)) {
            $this->$f();
        } 
        $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
```

Comment: This works, however doesn't really explain why the curly brace method we are currently using no longer works on PHP 5.5.9. Any idea's?

Comment: PHP has some quirks when it comes to nesting operations.  It doesn't handle nesting very well, in general.  It can't even do   somefunction( array(1,2,3) );

Comment: EDIT: well the latest version of php may have fixed the array issue.  Overall, PHP is not the most logically designed language   :-)

Comment: Though, if you do use braces, I think it's also missing a $ in front of them.  For example: $ab = 1;  echo ${'a' . 'b'};

Comment: It seems to work just `$this->{$variable . '_suffice'}()` on older version however can't see any reference as to why. We'll have to mass update the application to be more inline with what you've suggested or `call_user_fun`

Comment: As an alternative fix, try putting the $ before the braces as in ${  }.  The entire concatenated string needs to be the variable.    If that works, you might be able to do a global find/replace on finding $this->{ , replace with $this->${